# Characterizing measures on Borel sets.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Given a topological space $X$ we can generate a sigma algebra $\mathcal{M}$ on $X$ by taking the smallest sigma algebra containing all the open sets in $X$.

I wonder if in this situation it is possible to fully characterize a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ by defining its values on open sets in $X$.

I suspect it might be, but I might be wrong so I'd like a confirmation, or maybe to be even more specific on can we characterize a measure by defining $\mu$ on a basis for the topology in $X$ (or subbasis)?

As a special case consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ and as open $\left(a,b\right), -\infty \leq a \leq b \leq + \infty$, can I characterize a measure by simply defining $\mu(\left(a,b\right))$?

Comment: Changed the question, should be better now.

Comment: In general no, consider for example the counting measure on $\Bbb{Q}$ (as a subset of $\Bbb{R}$) and $\infty \cdot \lambda$ with $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure. If the measure in question is sigma finite w.r.t. open sets, then uniqueness does hold.

Comment: Right, I just see a bunch of theorems (variations of Riesz representation theorem). And I wonder if somewhat they can be used to workout the measure expression somewhat (as a formula).

Comment: @PhoemueX any proof of the "uniqueness" statement?

Comment: See Here: mpaldridge.github.io/teaching/ma40042-notes-08.pdf